# Doctrine2 sort by certain string value

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

For example I have blog posts table with status of publication(new, moderation, archive).

How I can get entities where posts with status "moderation" will be in first place?

I know what I can resolve this issue with PHP and custom sorting but how I can do this with Doctrine 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a custom DQL function. This is an example of something that might work with MySQL's `order by field` functionality:

```
class CustomOrder extends FunctionNode
{
    public $field = null;
    public $customerOrder = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->field = $parser->StringPrimary() 
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->secondDateExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'FIELD(' .
            $this->field->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' .
            $this->customOrder->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
        ')'; 
    }
}
```

Which you would call like this `Order By CustomOrder('status', "'new', 'moderation', 'archive'")` in your DQL query.

I think that doing a custom sort in PHP is equally valid for your use case unless you are reusing the custom order function in many places.